# Regex matching a date and time

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match a specific datetime format in PHP's regex:

```
dd-mm-YYYY HH:ii:ss
```

It should always be in that format. Meaning that for example when it is the first day of the month there must be a leading zero. E.g.:

```
01-01-2013 01:01:01
```

I tried it with the following pattern:

```
^[0-12]{2}-[0-31]{2}-[0-9]{4} [0-23]{2}:[0-59]{2}:[0-59]{2}$
```

But the above pattern fails on timestamps like: `09-05-2013 19:45:10`.

http://rubular.com/r/eGBAhwiNCR

I understand this may not be the correct approach to validate a date time like this, but I really want to know what is wrong with the above.

Comment: You can't use have a number between 0 and 12 like this: [0-12] means all characters between 0 and 1, and the character 2. It is like [012]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you are checking the "ranges", for example `[0-12]` at the beginning.  That is a character class, and it is telling the regex to match 0 through 1, and then 2.  So if you added more numbers in after the 1st one, it isn't working as you are expecting.  Changing your regex slightly (focused on the `[0-12]` initial), `[0-319]{2}-[0-12]{2}-[0-9]{4} [0-23]{2}:[0-59]{2}:[0-59]{2}$`, would match `09-01-2011 11:11:10`.

Ensuring there are valid numbers for each of those spaces requires a little thinking outside the box.  The regex:

`(0[1-9]|[12][\d]|3[0-2])-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-[\d]{4} (0[1-9]|1[\d]|2[0-3]):(0[1-9]|[1-5][\d]):(0[1-9]|[1-5][\d])$`

will work for what you are expecting with the [regex you attempted](http://rubular.com/r/PR4l6T8AQi).

If you break it down into smaller pieces it makes sense (it looks really scary at the beginning).  Looking at the first piece (0-31 for "days").

`(0[1-9]|[12][\d]|3[0-2])`

This is using an or to handle 3 different cases.

1. `0[1-9]` - a zero followed by any number between 1-9.  We don't want `[0-9]{2}` since that will allow numbers like `00`.  So a number is valid if it starts with `0` and has any other number after it (for single digit days).
2. `[12][\d]` - a `1 or 2` followed by any digit.  This allows the numbers `10-29` to be valid.
3. `3[0-2]` - a `3` followed by anything `0` through `2` matching `30`, `31`, and `32`.

Broken down, it's not too bad but this pattern is then carried out for each "field" in your date.  So this regex validates on each field being valid... but a better way to confirm valid dates maybe needed.  **This doesn't get into the complexity of checking if you can have `30-02` for example, where February doesn't have 30 days.**

Answer (score 7):

`[0-12]{2}` matches not the numbers `0` till `12`. Instead it's a character class allowing `0` to `1` and also the number `2`. The subsequent quantifier just allows the repetition of those, meanding 0,1 or 2 repeated two times.

Your other placeholders follow the same non-functioning scheme.

It's best to resort to `\d{2}` or `\d{4}` if you can't google a better regex. Even better yet, just use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime) to verify the format.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$
```

Comment: This would match against all `0`'s and numbers like `99` for month.

Comment: @Walls Seriously?  You're gonna downvote me for that?  Your own solution isn't any more valid - it allows dates like February 31.  It matches the *pattern* properly, which should then be fed into a PROPER date-checker instead of trying to do it all by regex.

Comment: @Walls Someone else had already given a good answer about why.  I just gave some code that would do exactly what was needed.  I don't see any reason to repeat someone else's perfectly good answer when I can just upvote theirs and then add the part they didn't put up.

Answer (score 0):

The example of validation is in php but the regex is standard

```
/*pass the date you wanna validate as parameter to the function.
The function returns true if it is valid and false if the date passed is not valid
*/   
function DateValid($date){
    //format will be fr if the date is in french format and en if the date is in en format
    $format='';
    //regex that tests if the date is in french format or english, if not in one of these two then it is not valid
    if(preg_match("#^(\d{1,2})[\-./ ](\d{1,2})[\-./ ](\d{4})(?: (\d{1,2})(?:[ .-](\d{1,2})){1,2})?$#",$date,$m)){
        $format='fr';
    }elseif (preg_match('#^(\d{4})[-. ](\d{1,2})[-. ](\d{1,2})(?: (\d{1,2})(?:[ .-](\d{1,2})){1,2})?$#', $date, $m)) {
        $format='en';
    }else{
         echo '<p style="font-size:150px">not english nor french</p>';
        return false;
    }
    //If it is french format or English then check if the date is correct
     if($format=='fr'){
         if (checkdate($m[2], $m[1], $m[3]) == false || $m[4] >= 24 || $m[5] >= 60 || $m[6] >= 60) {
            echo '<p style="font-size:150px">Not valid french</p>';
            return false;
        }else{
             echo '<p style="font-size:150px">Valid french</p>';
             return true;
        }
     }elseif($format=='en'){
         if (checkdate($m[2], $m[3], $m[1]) == false || $m[4] >= 24 || $m[5] >= 60 || $m[6] >= 60) {
             echo '<p style="font-size:150px">Not valid english</p>';
             return false;
        }else{
            echo '<p style="font-size:150px">Valid english</p>';
            return true;
        }
     }
}
```